# "UnreachableBrowserException" and "UnixUtils may not be used on Windows exception" after driver.quit while using MarionetteDriver

Tags: selenium, firefox, firefox-marionette

Environment- Firefox 48.0.2 and Selenium 3.0.0-beta2 versions ,i am getting below error -

> 1472824777259 Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 61096 [Child 5848]
>   WARNING: pipe error: 109: file
>   c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc,
>   line 343
>
> [Child 4048] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file
>   c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp,
>   line 2046 Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error
>   communicating with the remote browser. It may have died. Build info:
>   version: '3.0.0-beta2', revision: '2aa21c1', time: '2016-08-02
>   15:03:28 -0700' System info: host: 'VM7-JDB-068', ip: '10.60.88.67',
>   os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_51' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
>   Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false,
>   marionette=true, appBuildId=20160823121617, version=, platform=XP,
>   proxy={}, command_id=1, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false,
>   browserVersion=48.0.2, platformVersion=6.1,
>   XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=Firefox,
>   takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true,
>   platformName=Windows_NT, device=desktop}] Session ID:
>   499ab4bb-406d-4252-8b5d-808b22831595  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:670)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:706)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:531)
>     at firefox_java.sample.main(sample.java:19) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: UnixUtils may not be used on Windows
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.getProcessId(ProcessUtils.java:188)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.getPID(UnixProcess.java:222)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.access$300(UnixProcess.java:201)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.destroy(UnixProcess.java:132)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:155)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.stop(DriverService.java:196)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:94)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:649)
>     ... 3 more  on    driver.quit();

Here is my Java code:

```
 String marionetteDriverLocation = "\\Lib\\geckodriver.exe";  
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", marionetteDriverLocation);  
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
 driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");

 driver.quit();
```

Could you please help .
    Thanks

Comment: driver.quit() has some issues. You can check here.https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2701

Comment: Thanks for update.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `MarionetteDriver` but initializing `FirefoxDriver()`.

Please try with `WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver(cap);` it should work.

Comment: I tried above line but it is giving me warning  that MarionetteDriver is deprecated.I can try again if you tell what desired capabilities (cap)you have set up while passing as constructor .

Comment: I am using `DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working copy that I just now tried. If it doesn't work, then there should be problem with selenium jar or gecodriver.exe you are using.

```
public class MarrionateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        cap.setCapability("marionette", true);
        WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver(cap);
        driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.org");
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but now even my webdriver instance does't closed. Just to give you update about my versions -Firefox -48.0.2 ,Selenium 3.0.0-beta2,and geckodriver v0.10.0 (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). kindly check and let me know if i need different geckodriver versions. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some error log or something to check why your driver instance is not getting close ?

Comment: There is no error comes it simply passes from driver.close() without closing firefox and in console it gives below message -1472803626670 Marionette INFO Listening on port 56277
1472803628128 Marionette INFO startBrowser 49ca3ffc-a004-4f92-928e-29e708ed7002
1472803628140 Marionette INFO sendAsync 49ca3ffc-a004-4f92-928e-29e708ed7002
1472803628519 Marionette INFO sendAsync 49ca3ffc-a004-4f92-928e-29e708ed7002
1472803628854 Marionette INFO sendAsync 49ca3ffc-a004-4f92-928e-29e708ed7002  .

Comment: when i am using driver.quit() then  browser is closing but org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException error message also coming.